# Wrong value returned when converting from raw character to hex equivalent

Tags: c, binary, hex, ascii, data-conversion

I have an application where the input is a raw set of bytes and I want to see the two-digit hex code of each of those bytes. For now I'm trying to get the proper hex code for one byte. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char hexvc; //= ascii code for hex value
char aval[2]={0xFF,0x00}; //Our raw 1 byte data. can't print actual code here
char hexv[20]; //value for output
memset(hexv,0,19); //clear output
hexvc=strtol(aval,NULL,16) & 0xFF;
if (hexvc != '\0'){
    sprintf(hexv,"%02hx",hexvc);
}else{
    //hexvc always equals 0. why not FFh?
    strcpy(hexv,"00");
}
printf("%s\n",hexv);
return 0;
}
```

I expected to see ff appear on the screen, but instead I see 00.
How do I fix this?

And if I change `0xFF` after `aval[2]=` to `0x31` or `'1'` (since 1 is the actual value for ascii code 0x31) then I want to see `31` appear on the screen.

Comment: `strtol` converts a string to a long integer. The first character in the string that you're passing in is 0xFF, followed by a null terminator. You seem to need a function that does the opposite of `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

aval[2]={0xFF,0x00};

This is not ascii.

aval[]={'f', 'f',0x00};

Or

aval[]="ff";

And try again

Answer (score -1):

```
char aval[] = {0x66, 0x66, 0x00};
```

`0x66` is char `'f'` in ascii